# Abrir e fechar conexão cada vez que roda o looping

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho um aplicação que executa uma `procedure`, salva em um `DataTable` e depois faz um `looping` para adicionar os dados em uma planilha excel.
Minha dúvida é, se eu abrir e fechar a conexão a cada `insert` vai aumentar o tempo de execução do processo e/ou posso abrir/fechar apenas uma vez enquanto faz todo o processo ?

Segue código:

```
private void AtualizarPerformanceEntrega()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = ExportPerformanceEntrega();

        string dir = Session.SessionID;
        string sFileXLSX = Server.MapPath(dir) + @"\Performance_Entrega_base.xls";

        if (File.Exists(sFileXLSX))
        {
            string strConnXLSX = (@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " + sFileXLSX +"; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;ReadOnly=False';");

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strConnXLSX))
                {
                    string strSQL;
                    OleDbCommand cmd;
                    //OleDbDataReader dts;
                    if ((string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "No Prazo" || (string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "Fora do Prazo" || (string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "Antes do Prazo")
                    {
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Base Entregue$] " +
                           " (NFEmpresa,NFNumero,NFSerie,NFCliente,NFPedido,NFCidade,NFUF,Regiao,NFTransp,NomeTransp,DataEmbarque,DataPrevEntrega,DataEntrega,StatusEntrega,DiasAtraso,CodOcorrencia,DescrOcorrencia) " +
                           " VALUES (@NFEmpresa, @NFNumero, @NFSerie, @NFCliente, @NFPedido, @NFCidade, @NFUF, @Regiao, @NFTransp, @NomeTransp, @DataEmbarque, @DataPrevEntrega, " +
                           " @DataEntrega, @StatusEntrega, @DiasAtraso, @CodOcorrencia, @DescrOcorrencia)";
                            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFEmpresa"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFNumero"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFSerie"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFCliente"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFPedido"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFCidade"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFUF"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["Regiao"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFTransp"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NomeTransp"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataEmbarque"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataPrevEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["StatusEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DiasAtraso"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["CodOcorrencia"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DescrOcorrencia"]));
                            //Abrindo a conexão
                            connection.Open();
                            //Executando o INSERT
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            //Fechando a conexão
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    if ((string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "Não Entregue")
                    {               
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Base Não Entregue$] " +
                          " (NFEmpresa,NFNumero,NFSerie,NFCliente,NFPedido,NFCidade,NFUF,Regiao,NFTransp,NomeTransp,DataEmbarque,DataPrevEntrega,DataEntrega,StatusEntrega,DiasAtraso,CodOcorrencia,DescrOcorrencia) " +
                          " VALUES (@NFEmpresa, @NFNumero, @NFSerie, @NFCliente, @NFPedido, @NFCidade, @NFUF, @Regiao, @NFTransp, @NomeTransp, @DataEmbarque, @DataPrevEntrega, " +
                          " @DataEntrega, @StatusEntrega, @DiasAtraso, @CodOcorrencia, @DescrOcorrencia)";
                            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFEmpresa"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFNumero"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFSerie"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFCliente"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFPedido"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFCidade"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFUF"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["Regiao"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFTransp"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NomeTransp"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataEmbarque"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataPrevEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["StatusEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DiasAtraso"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["CodOcorrencia"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DescrOcorrencia"]));
                            //Abrindo a conexão
                            connection.Open();
                            //Executando o INSERT
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            //Fechando a conexão
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    //Fechando qualquer conexão que tenha ficado aberta, evitando o load infinito na página
                    connection.Close();   
                }               
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A performance vai ser impactada negativamente se você abrir e fechar conexões para cada item no laço. Então a resposta mais curta e rápida é que você deve abrir a conexão antes do `foreach`, e fechar depois. Você já faz uso de boas práticas por criar as conexões com `using`, então a última dica que falta é: caso os dados sejam dependentes uns dos outros, utilizar transações pode ser um bom negócio.

Agora, sobre como a performance é impactada.

#### No cliente

Existe um consumo de tempo de processador para se abrir e fechar conexão, e você vai pagar esse custo cada vez que fizer essas coisas. Mas esse custo é pequeno.

Existe um custo de alocação de memória para se manter uma conexão aberta. Você já usa boas práticas (`using`), então a plataforma e o Garbage Collector já fazem toda a parte lógica para você, e o custo é relativamente baixo. Mas em geral é melhor manter a quantidade de objetos alocada para isso a menor possível.

#### No servidor

É aqui que o bicho pega. O problema não é o custo de se manter uma conexão individual aberta, mas sim o fato de que servidores de banco de dados em geral têm que atender a muitos clientes de uma vez. Ficar abrindo e fechando conexões a esmo pode sobrecarregar o servidor.

Os bancos mais atuais utilizam um mecanismo para lidar com isso chamado "*pooling* de conexões"; *Pooling* poderia ser traduzido livremente como rodízio. O servidor mantém um conjunto de objetos internos de conexão vivos por tempo indeterminado e altera somente propriedades específicas para variar os clientes atendidos. Cada cliente que pede uma conexão é atendido por um desses objetos, o primeiro que estiver livre. Quando todos os objetos do rodízio estiverem ocupados, os próximos clientes aguardarão atendimento em fila. Por padrão, o SQL Server 2016 mantém um rodízio de 100 conexões, mas esse número pode ser configurado. O rodízio pode ser inclusive desligado, caso seja mais conveniente.

Por que isso é importante? Quando uma conexão do servidor é liberada, ela demora um tempo até ficar disponível novamente no rodízio. Se a sua aplicação for a única que utiliza o banco e o seu laço tiver menos de 100 itens, ou se todos demorarem bastante, você não sentirá muito impacto.

Mas se:

- várias instâncias da sua aplicação acessarem o banco ao mesmo tempo, ou;
- A operação de inserção for super rápida e o laço tiver mais de 100 itens, ou;
- por qualquer motivo que seja, o *pooling* de conexões estiver desligado ou reduzido...

Então você pode sentir uma diferença na performance da aplicação caso teste as duas situações: conexão aberta para cada item ou conexão aberta uma única vez para o laço.